# I want to Block url in webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Heres the acitivity of my code I want to like to block external link like if someone click on another `webpage` he or she cannot go to that `webpage`.

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        String url = "https://www.example.com";
        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);
        web.loadUrl(url);

        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +

                        "document.getElementsByClassName('header_wrapper')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('footer-contact')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('footer-social')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementById('footer_bottom').style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementById('footer_content').style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementById('core_mobile_menu').style.display='none'; " +
                        "document.getElementById('catapult-cookie-bar').style.display='none'; " +


                        "})()");
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I add this line of code? Or is it possible if you can show me where you added it thanks

Comment: Its already mention in your question you have already set the WebViewClient just override one more method which is shouldOverrideUrlLoading() . And you are good to go .

Comment: If I want to add notification how can I do it ?

Comment: add notification ?? Where? Explain . or post a new question cause it seems totally  different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as per your code

```
 public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        String url = "https://www.example.com";
        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);
        web.loadUrl(url);

        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);

  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){

       return true;
   }
     });
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to add notification how can I add in?

Comment: Yes you can use JavaScriptInterface in Java file and call this function in your particular webpage

Comment: What would be the code ? Can you show me please I'm new to this

Comment: please check my given answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686798/adding-notification-on-webview/47708133#47708133

Answer (score 0):

```
      webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
       //True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and 
       // handle the url itself, otherwise return false.
       return true;
   }
     });
```

**Use Like this :**

```
     WebView webview = new WebView(context);
     webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
     {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
         {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where should I add this line of code? Or is it possible if you can show me where you added it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will also handle `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` deprecation in Nougat and above

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClent() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // reject anything other by returning true
        return true;
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String url=request.getUrl().toString();
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }

        // reject anything other
        return true;
    }
}
```